# how can I reenter my flowchart workflow at a previous higher level

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I have a .xamlx flowchart workflow that models an approval process.  if the submitter changes the document before the flowchart has finished, I want the submitter to 'resubmit' the document.  I thought I would just be able to call the first receive activity again, but I think the workflow is recognizing it is already further along and is exiting.

Do I need to 'cancel' the workflow before 'resubmitting'?  Or perhaps I just need another method later in the flowchart that the submitter calls?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Maurice was correct MOL.  I could copy the original Receive to a later place in the workflow.  But in order for it to work correctly, the first receive needed both it CorrelatesOn and CorrelationInitializers set to the same Correlation Handle variable.  The 'copy' only needed the CorrelatesOn property set.  Thay may have been obvious but since I didn't know it, I'm documenting here in case anyone else gets the same issue.

Comment: The first one should only need the CorrelationInitializers and the second one only the CorrelatesOn and you can uncheck the CanCreateInstance though it doesn't hurt of it is checked. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I retested this as many ways as I could think of and it only works with both properties set on the first Receive.

Comment: yes it's only executed once IF i configure it as above, otherwise it keeps getting executed whenever I call the method

Answer (score 1):

You can create any branch you want in a flowchart. So you can just loop back to the top of the workflow. You do need to model this explicitly in your workflow though.

Comment: essentially you are saying that I need another method in my service that I can call that will loop back, correct?  After I posted this, that is essentially the direction I took too.  I was looking for another way so I could keep the methods I was exposing minimal, but this works.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you should be able to use a copy of the original Receive activity. That way the client doesn't see another operation in the WSDL. I think it should work because you are not activating 2 identical Receive activities.

Comment: oh, that is interesting.  I didn't think of that even though I've used it elsewhere.  I'd still need a pick to branch the code, but at least my interface would still be clean and my UI ignorant.  Thank you!

Comment: I spoke too soon, that did not work.  Even though the designer let me copy the Receive whenever I try call that method the workflow enters at the top and 'backs out'.  There is no error, it just steps out of the workflow and that's it.